# Error when extending AdvancedDataGridRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

I have set the itemrenderer package like that:

package myrenderers
{
    import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer;

```
public class theHeaderRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer
{
    public function theHeaderRenderer()
    {
        super();
        setStyle("verticalAlign","middle"); 
    }
}
```

}

However when I include the following lines in my AdvancedDataGridColumn tag,

```
            <fx:Component>
                <myrenderers:theHeaderRenderer"/>
            </fx:Component>

        </mx:headerRenderer>
```

```
            <fx:Component>
                <renderers:someotherrenderer/>
            </fx:Component>

        </mx:itemRenderer>
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.controls.dataGridClasses::DataGridListData@ac84f81 to mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridListData.
    at mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses::AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer/set listData()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\datavisualization\src\mx\controls\advancedDataGridClasses\AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer.as:232]
    at mx.controls::DataGrid/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::calculateHeaderHeight()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\DataGrid.as:2182]
    at mx.controls.dataGridClasses::DataGridHeader/measure()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\dataGridClasses\DataGridHeader.as:201]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/measureSizes()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8216]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8140]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:617]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:709]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1072]`

Can anyone suggest how I can come across this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd recommend you extend your custom headerRenderer from `AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer` instead of `AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer`.

Second, it looks like you are mixing the `mx:DataGrid` with the `mx:AdvancedDataGrid`. I guess that's the cause for your type coercion error. Make sure that your MXML looks something like this:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="foo" headerRenderer="myrenderers.theHeaderRenderer"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```